# Going too fast to learn 'Linked lists' while not completely comfortable with Pointers? #C Language beginner

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, linked-list

I currently finished two chapters that covered 'Pointers' in a book.

My current sub-topics that i need more practice with are
- using pointer notations instead of array notations and
- using array of pointers (to some extent)

Doubts:

1) Before i move on to learning 'linked lists', should i wait and first build my comfort with pointers to a greater level or learning 'linked lists' will help me with pointers?

2) Could you point me to a link or something where i can find 'pointers' related exercises to practice?

3)what are some important sub-topics within pointers that i MUST focus on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My (this is ofc subjective) is:

1. Yes, a typical implementation of a linked list are a set of Nodes with each node having a pointer to the Node following it (in the case of a singly linked list). I think it's best to at least be comfortable with null-pointers (use nullptr in C++11) and pointer dereferencing. Also, it's good to understand what for example

   ```
   if(p == q)
       // do something
   ```

   means, if p and q are pointers.
2. [Pointer exercises](http://condor.depaul.edu/ntomuro/courses/309/notes/pointer_exercises.html) (Quick google search)
3. Above the ones I mentioned in (1) I would say pointer arithmetic is always good. For example,

   ```
   p[i];
   *(p+i);
   ```

   these expressions are equivalent (p is a pointer). I am sure others will contribute much more good pointers (pun intended) on what to focus on.